# How to work input[type=text]:invalid with html 5 required?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form I'm using HTML5 validation that is working fine, Now I want to add input border color red instead of HTML default validation message, but border color is by default displaying, how to fix it?

What I tried:-

```css
input[type=text]:invalid {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-body">

<label>Full Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  required><br>
<label>Phone</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  required><br>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  required><br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Comment: By definition if it’s required, and there is no text, that makes it invalid :) So I wouldn’t say it’s by ‘default displaying’. There are many similar questions on SO about this. Have none helped you?

Comment: You have to add code that sets a class on the form when submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below code? here It will have red border only when you focus input. However If you wish to display border when focus is lost after focusing once then you may need to write some javascript code instead of css.

```
input:focus:invalid {border: 1px red solid;}
```

Comment: thank you @Santosh Kadam i want this one!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the form and base the css rules off of that.

```js
document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.form.classList.add('submitted')
})
```

```css
form.submitted input[type=text]:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: 0
}
```

```html
<form class="form-body">
  <label>Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required><br>
  <label>Phone</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required><br>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" required><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```